# Connect salesforce to ftp using http request

Tags: ftp, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to connect my salesforce account to an FTP server so that I do not have to use the local system for the storage of any files coming from FTP. I have tried connecting to the FTP server using CLI which I have done successfully as I can see the files coming from the FTP.

Can somebody explain how i ccould connect the ftp server to my salesforce account using an **http** request and also how could i transfer and use the .Csv file to update/import the data into the salesforce custom object**

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to import data into Salesforce, however, FTP to Salesforce isn't one of them. I would either use the Salesforce Data Loader, if you have access to this data at the console, or use the Salesforce API for whatever platform you program in, to create a program that uses your FTP and can parse your data and deliver it to Salesforce through the API.

Comment: thanks for reply 
but client requirement is that they want to import/update data into salesforce object from ftp server directly no file or coding onto the  local system

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct FTP access into a Salesforce object. I'm sure you can have an intermediate system that can run a job to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this directly. You might look at using an intermediary system like TIBCO or Informatica. SFDC specifically prohibits FTP access.

Using your staging system, have it kick off an Apex bulk API job to do the import. You could do it with a cheap cloud server running your FTP box and a script that kicks off when a file is created in the specified directory, and then when the API job is done, archive or delete the original file and log files.